# Реализация удаления изображений

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Имеется сайт с заявками, где есть выпадающий список отображающий в миниатюре прикреплённые файлы к заявке(изображения). Можно посмотреть их, но в Pretty Photo, насколько я понял, нет возможности удаления. Используется Fat Free Framework.

---

В api/index.php добавил:

```
F3::route('POST /order/images/@ID [ajax]', 'OrderController->deleteImages');
```

В контроллёр Order.php добавил

```
public function deleteImages()
{
    try {
        $data = $_POST['data'];
        $queryFileName = Dbh::getInstance()->prepare("DELETE FROM attaches WHERE attachID=?");
        $queryFileName->execute(array($data));
    } catch (Exception $e){
        $this->output['error'] = true;
        $this->output['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

Сделал вывод окна с изображениями и чекбокс для отметки изображений для удаления, прикрепил JQuery по нажатию. Всё работает, никак не пойму, как это можно связать...
Основная веб-страница(отрывок-окно):

```
<div id="fileDelete" class="modal modal-userinfo hide fade">
    <?php
        $Attaches = GetOrderAttaches($orderDetail->getID(), ATTACH_OWNER_ACCESSOR);
    ?>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h3>Выберите файлы для удаления из заявки</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-vertical">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="checkboxes">Прикреплённые файлы:</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <ul class="thumbnails">
                            <?php foreach ($Attaches as $Attach) :?>
                                <li class="span1">
                                    <label class="checkbox" for="checkboxes-<?php echo $Attach['AttachID']; ?>">
                                        <?php echo $Attach['FileName']; ?>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="fileToDelete" id="checkboxes-<?php echo $Attach['AttachID']?>"
                                               value="<?php echo $Attach['AttachID']; ?>">

                                        <a href="<?php echo('/upload/files/' . $Attach['FileName']); ?>"
                                           class="thumbnail">
                                            <?php
                                                $thumbnail_src = (mb_strtolower(pathinfo($Attach['FileName'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) == 'pdf') ? 'pdf.jpg' : $Attach['FileName'];
                                            ?>
                                            <img src="<?php echo('/upload/files/thumbnail/' . $thumbnail_src); ?>"
                                                 alt="<?php //echo $Attach['RealFileName'] ?> ">
                                        </a>
                                    </label>
                                </li>
                            <?php endforeach ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <span class="btn btn-danger enabled">
            <span>Удалить</span>
            <input id="filedeletebtn" name="deletingfiles" type="button" multiple>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Скрипт, отвечающий за кнопку удаления:

```
$('#filedeletebtn').on('click', function(){
    var iSelectedFiles = $('#fileDelete').find("input:checkbox:checked").serializeArray();
    var count = iSelectedFiles.length;
    if (count != 0) {
        var html = 'Вы действительно хотите удалить выбранные фото? Элементов: ' + count;
        bootbox.confirm(html, function (result) {
            if (result) {
                $.each(iSelectedFiles, function (index, file) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'api/order/images/' + file.value,
                        data: file.value
                    })
                        .fail(function (file, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            bootbox.alert('Возникла проблема при удалении изображений: </br>' + file.statusText);
                        });
                });
            }
        });
    } else {
        bootbox.alert('Выберите файлы для удаления!');
    }
});
```

Как всё это можно оживить, чтобы работало? Доделал, а не работает((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, я это сделал!
В файле контроллёра надо было изменить на строку

```
$data = $_POST['value'];
```

А в файле скрипта в AJAX надо было изменить на строки

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'api/order/images/' + file.value,
      data: file
})
```

И над этой мелочью я ломал голову весь день) Надеюсь, кому-то будет полезен мой опыт.